# Python: where is htmllib folder?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

Where can I find the htmllib folder. It is not in my site-packages folder. I want to read the code of HTMLParser in htmllib.
I found this code online

```
class TrackingParser(htmllib.HTMLParser):
   """Try to keep accurate pointer of parsing location."""
  def __init__(self, writer, *args):
    htmllib.HTMLParser.__init__(self, *args)
    self.writer = writer
  def parse_starttag(self, i):
    index = htmllib.HTMLParser.parse_starttag(self, i)
    self.writer.index = index
    return index
  def parse_endtag(self, i):
    self.writer.index = i
    return htmllib.HTMLParser.parse_endtag(self, i)
```

I want to find out what is parse_starttag and parse_endtag returning?

Comment: I looked at the code but there is no parse_starttag or parse_endtag in the class?

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: Some text editors have a "Go to definition" function. What are you using?

Comment: I work mostly on sublimeText2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[htmllib.HTMLParser](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6c47c6d2033e/Lib/htmllib.py#l23)  inherits [parse_starttag](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6c47c6d2033e/Lib/sgmllib.py#l238) and [parse_endtag](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6c47c6d2033e/Lib/sgmllib.py#l311) methods from [sgmllib.SGMLParser](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6c47c6d2033e/Lib/sgmllib.py#l60).

Comment: Thanks. I had been searching this for a while never thought SGMLlib is being used by htmllib. What exactly is the difference between two?

Comment: @mousecoder From the [docs on sgmllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sgmllib.html): *This module defines a class SGMLParser which serves as the basis for parsing text files formatted in SGML (Standard Generalized Mark-up Language). In fact, it does not provide a full SGML parser — it only parses SGML insofar as it is used by HTML, and the module only exists as a base for the htmllib module*

Answer (score 1):

There is no folder.

There is `htmllib.py` in the `Lib` directory. You'll also find `sgmllib.py` there (which is imported by `htmllib`) with the definition of `parse_starttag` and `parse_endtag`.

[image: screenshot]